# How to compile AndroidManifest.xml programmatically on Android?

Tags: android, package, apk, android-manifest, recompile

I want to know how to implement a apk editor which can edit app name and version.

A way I can figure out takes several steps:

1. unzip apk file
2. modify app name and version in AndroidManifest.xml
3. replace the AndroidManifest.xml with the modified one
4. compress them into a new apk file
5. sign and align it

I can do all the steps above except Step 2. The AndroidManifest.xml file is compiled and cannot be parsed as normal xml file. I know apktool can compile and decompile it but I cannot find a easy way to run apktool on Android after several hours searching. I also cannot find any open-source apk editors(what I need is not only a apk editor, I want to develop another app based on it).

Comment: What is your original task? Why do you need such heavy customization?

Comment: @Yurii Tsap, something like a open-source JavaScript IDE on Android. A new feature I'm designing is building an apk from js.

Comment: So couldn't you just build all the project with gradle, like Android Studio does? Can't it be a default workflow?

Comment: @Yurii Tsap, I have no idea about running gradle or other building tools **on Android**. My JavaScript IDE is just an Android app so I should find a way of building apk **on mobile phone**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find some projects for reading and writing AXML(Android XML) and resources.arsc:

- [ArscEditor](https://github.com/cmeiyuan/ArscEditor)
- [axml](https://code.google.com/p/axml/)

So I can wirte an apk builder with them. For more information, see my repo [Auto.js-ApkBuilder](https://github.com/hyb1996/Auto.js-ApkBuilder).